# How to change htmlText to all fields in data grid

Tags: livecode

How to change htmlText to all fields in group "DGP"? I am using this code:

```
repeat with x = 1 to 16--the number of lines in dataarray
      put the htmlText of field x  of group "DGP"  into myHtml
      replace ss with "<font bgcolor=" & quote & "green" & quote & ">" & ss & "</font>" in myHtml 
      set the htmlText  of field x of  group "DGP" to myHtml
   end repeat
```

If I write `the number of lines in dataarray` instead of `16`, the following error occurs:

> group "NDGP": execution error at line 35 (Chunk: no such object), char 11

I think this is because of the small size of the grid. When I changed the code to `16` it works, but if I scroll down, `the bgcolor` is lost.

Comment: You should create a DataGrid template with the desired background colour(s).

Comment: i only want to change my replaced word with color

Comment: Is dataarray really an array? Arrays don't have lines. They have keys. Can you please check if the datagrid documentation says anything at all about htmlText?

Comment: no, its just a name. but the same code works in scrolling field. then why not in datagrid

Comment: Because dataGrids are no fields. DataGrids are groups. Groups don't have an htmlText property.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed the `htmlText` propeties of the fields of a datagrid, you would ignore the datagrid-specific properties. The datagrid might even completely ignore the changes and display the original data as soon as an update of the visible part of the data is triggered, e.g. by scrolling.

You should not change the `htmlText` property of individual fields of a datagrid.